# SQL statement which returns id and splits comma separated values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following data:

```
NodeId ExternalIds
50     601
56     700,701
```

How do I write an SQL-statement which splits the ExternalIds-column and returns:

```
NodeId ExternalIds
50     601
56     700
56     701
```

I have found a lot of user defined functions and procedure which splits a string into a table, but I cannot get any of them to work

**edit**

```
create table #tmpTable (NodeId int, ExternalIds varchar(50))
insert into #tmpTable (NodeId,ExternalIds) values (50, '600')
insert into #tmpTable (NodeId,ExternalIds) values (56, '700,701')

select NodeId, 
    (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SplitString](select * from #tmpTable,',') where NodeId=56)from #tmpTable)
where NodeId=56
drop table #tmpTable
```

where SplitString is based on the following:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @myString varchar(500),
    @deliminator varchar(10)
)
RETURNS 
@ReturnTable TABLE 
(
    -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [part] [varchar](50) NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
        Declare @iSpaces int
        Declare @part varchar(50)

        --initialize spaces
        Select @iSpaces = charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0)
        While @iSpaces > 0

        Begin
            Select @part = substring(@myString,0,charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0))

            Insert Into @ReturnTable(part)
            Select @part

    Select @myString = substring(@mystring,charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0)+ len(@deliminator),len(@myString) - charindex(' ',@myString,0))


            Select @iSpaces = charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0)
        end

        If len(@myString) > 0
            Insert Into @ReturnTable
            Select @myString

    RETURN 
END
```

I am trying to get some data from the database for Umbraco (the cms), which is designed with the comma-separated values.

thanks
Thomas

Comment: please show what happened when you tried to get these functions to work.

Comment: "I have found a lot of user defined functions and procedure which splits a string into a table, but I cannot get any of them to work" what have you tried?

Comment: Perhaps you should properly design your database. Data should almost NEVER be stored in a delimited list.

Comment: @HLGEM. Perhaps this is an effort to migrate the data to a table that is in 1NF?

Comment: Hi. I updated the question with my current sql

Comment: @HLGEM: Perhaps you shouldn't assume that the OP owns, or even has any ability to change the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select NodeId, 
       S.part
from #tmpTable
  cross apply [dbo].[SplitString](ExternalIds, ',') as S
```

Comment: Hi Mikael, I tried your solution but to my surprise, some of my values are truncated at the last alphabet.I have exactly same issue that Thomas posted except my list is ; and space delimited. For e.g., I have product_Name as PS CAS; SECURITY SOURCEONE and when applied the fxn, the one column appears as SECURITY SOURCEON with 'E' missing at the end. Any idea? TIA.

Comment: @Nemo I guess the split string function does not handle space as separator. Are you using the same as in the question here? It is not very efficient. Have a look [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) for alternatives.

Comment: @Mikael- Ty for the info. I went to to the link u posted. I thought to remove space after semicolon by using a SQLCLR function. So my column product_Name looks like PS CAS;SECURITY SOURCEONE Now my concern is how do I get new rows for each ID with the product_Name like PS CAS;SECURITY SOURCEONE w/o using the above SplitString fxn? I m new to SQLCLR but it seems to be good at handling these issue. No idea on how though. :( Any help?

Comment: @Nemo you should ask that as a new question to give others the chance to answer or point you to other resources or other questions that has the answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example of how to cursor over the data into your desired format. Note, this is more of a quick demo that doesn't currently use a split function. I would make two comments:
- imo cursor's should be avoided 
- as
   above commenter's have suggested try
   to avoid storing delimited data

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    NodeId int,
    ExternalID int
)
DECLARE @NodeId int
DECLARE @ExternalIds nvarchar(2000)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT NodeId, ExternalIDs
from dbo.test

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @NodeId, @ExternalIds   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
    WHILE (Charindex(',',@ExternalIds)>0)
    Begin
        INSERT INTO @Table (NodeId, ExternalId)
        SELECT @NodeId, 
            Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@ExternalIds,1,Charindex(',',@ExternalIds)-1)))

        SET @externalids = Substring(@ExternalIds,Charindex(',',@ExternalIds)+1,len(@ExternalIds))
    End

    INSERT INTO @Table (NodeId, ExternalId)
    Select @NodeId, Data = ltrim(rtrim(@ExternalIds))

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @NodeId, @ExternalIds  
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

SELECT * FROM @Table
```