# splitting strings in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 2 columns, one for id and one for country.

I've found some rows in the table where it looks like the below:

| ID | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | US and Canada |
| 2 | France and UK |

How can I write a query so that I find the rows and split the column so
I get the following result.

| ID | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | US |
| 1 | Canada |
| 2 | France |
| 2 | UK |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Substring after a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44670824/substring-after-a-space)

Comment: Do you have more than one `and`in a row?

Comment: Refer : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233037/sql-statement-which-returns-id-and-splits-comma-separated-values

Comment: @sddk I just have one

Comment: @GehanFernando Not applicable, check DBMS tag.

Comment: What will you do with `'Trinidad and Tobago'`? Or `'St Kitts and Nevis'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you have more than one `and` in a row? – sddk
>
> I just have one – jean10

```
SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Country, ' and ', 1) Country
FROM tablename
UNION 
SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Country, ' and ', -1)
FROM tablename
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' and ', 1) as country
        FROM 
           (      SELECT 1 AS id, 'US and CN' AS name 
            UNION SELECT 2 AS id, 'JP and KR' AS name
           ) as string_test_tbl
        UNION 
    SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' and ', -1) as country
        FROM 
           (      SELECT 1 AS id, 'US and CN' AS name 
            UNION SELECT 2 AS id, 'JP and KR' AS name
           ) as string_test_tbl
        ;
```